# discarding all elements of datetimeindex except first and last

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `datetimeindex`:

```
dates = DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01', '2022-03-02', '2022-03-03', '2022-03-04',
               '2022-03-05', '2022-03-06', '2022-03-07', '2022-03-08',
               '2022-03-09', '2022-03-10',
               ...
               '2022-06-06', '2022-06-07', '2022-06-08', '2022-06-09',
               '2022-06-10', '2022-06-11', '2022-06-12', '2022-06-13',
               '2022-06-14', '2022-06-15'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=107, freq='D')
```

I want to discard all elements except the first and last one. How do I do that? I tried this:

[dates[0]] + dates[-1]] but it returns an actual list of datetimes and not this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01', '2022-06-15'],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=2, freq='D')
```

Comment: `[...] + ...]` is invalid. You meant `[...] + [...]`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index with a list to select multiple items.

```
>>> dates[[0, -1]]
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01', '2022-06-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This is covered in the NumPy user guide under [Integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). In the Pandas user guide, there's related info under [Selection by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
print(dates[::len(dates)-1])
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-03-01', '2022-06-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

This is slicing using a step that skips right from the start to the end (explanation suggested by @wjandrea).

Comment: It might help to explain briefly how this works, since it's a bit counterintuitive. I'd write something like, "This is slicing using a step that skips right from the start to the end."